# Trouble defining a subset of Euclidean space

Tags: lean

I am using [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/) to try to formalize the notion of a subset of Euclidean space (R^n).

I have tried the following:

```
import analysis.real

def repeated_prod : ℕ → Type → Type
| 0 s := empty
| 1 s := s
| (n + 1) s := prod s (repeated_prod n s)

structure euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type :=
(space : set (repeated_prod n ℝ))

def euclidean_subset (M : Type) := ∃ n : ℕ, (set M) ⊆ (euclidean_space.mk n).space
```

To try putting in English:

1. The real numbers (R) are defined in the analysis component of [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover/mathlib).
2. We need to generalize this to k dimensions, so we want the Cartesian product of R with itself any number of times.
3. `repeated_prod` allows one to take an arbitrary type and apply the Cartesian product with itself multiple times.
4. `euclidean_space` is a specialization to the case of R.
5. We say that it is a `euclidean_subset` if there is a some Euclidean space (note: I am trying to avoid the mention of dimension so it is *some* R^n.) which the set (`M`) is subset of.

This however gives the error:

```
euclidean.lean:11:52: error: failed to synthesize type class instance for
M : Type,
n : ℕ
⊢ has_subset Type
euclidean.lean:11:74: error: maximum class-instance resolution depth has been reached (the limit can be increased by setting option 'class.instance_max_depth') (the class-instance resolution trace can be visualized by setting option 'trace.class_instances')
```

Although, I admittedly don't know what the default value for `trace.class_instances` is, I set it to `10000`, it took a bit longer, and the same error message was given, leading to me that it there error message is misleading. Can't seem to find a lot about this language, including the error message I got, any help resolving this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two compilation errors, although one of them is not visible. Firstly, you can't make a Euclidean space in the way you have tried to, with `mk`. I suggest changing from a structure to a def for the time being, since your structure only has one field:

```
def euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type := set (repeated_prod n ℝ)
```

Then a euclidean space of dimension n is simply `euclidean_space n`.

Secondly, Types are not the same as sets, so that's why Lean can't find an instance for `has_subset Type`. In the Calculus of Constructions, the type theory that Lean is based on, types can't *really* be subtypes of other types in the object-oriented programming sense - although you can use "subtype types" and/or coercions to simulate this. So that's what I've changed your code to do - rather than the `euclidean_subset` predicate trying to check for whether something is a subset, it instead checks that it is a subtype type of a `euclidean space n` for some `n`:

```
def euclidean_subset (M : Type) := ∃ (n : ℕ) (P : euclidean_space n → Prop), M = subtype P
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! I am only confused about one thing: "Firstly, you can't make a Euclidean space in the way you have tried to, with `mk`." I thought that structures were constrcuted with `mk` and according to [here](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/structures_and_records.html) they are supplied by default even if not explicitly declared. Did something change in Lean? Definitely accepting though as `def` is certainly the way to go.

Comment: The problem is not that you have called `mk`, it is that you have called `mk` with the type argument, instead of the constructor argument. That doesn't make sense. That's like saying "I want to create a vector of size 2" - to which the only appropriate response would be: you haven't supplied enough information - what should be in that vector?