# What makes the natural numbers so special with regards to timing out?

Tags: lean

In a previous [question I asked about formalizing subsets of Euclidean Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52617617/667648) I received the following response for how to create n-dimensional Euclidean space:

```
def euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type := set (repeated_prod n ℝ)
```

And I received the following response for creating a subset of Euclidean space:

```
def euclidean_subset (M : Type) := ∃ (n : ℕ) (P : euclidean_space n → Prop), M = subtype P
```

Running through my modified code everything compiled which was great and do believe the answer is (at least, mostly) correct. I wanted to try running some basic checks on the code. In particular, I would expect:

```
#reduce euclidean_space 2
```

to give:

```
ℝ × ℝ
```

well, it didn't. It timed out. I then proceeded, to try some other sets. I modified `euclidean_space` to be:

```
def euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type := set (repeated_prod n ℕ)
```

Although, no longer faithful to it's name, one should expect

```
#reduce euclidean_space 2
```

to give:

```
ℕ × ℕ
```

well, almost, it gives:

```
ℕ × ℕ → Prop
```

Given the result I removed the `set` call and redefined `euclidean_space` to be:

```
def euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type := (repeated_prod n ℕ)
```

which reducing produced the desired result. I then went back and replaced ℕ with ℝ:

```
def euclidean_space (n : ℕ) : Type := (repeated_prod n ℝ)
```

`euclidean_subset` still compiled, however `#reduce` still gives a timeout using ℝ. Why does ℕ not timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`real` is a definition, so it will be reduced as well:

```
def real := @cau_seq.completion.Cauchy ℚ _ _ _ abs _
```

https://github.com/leanprover/mathlib/blob/a243126efbd7ddef878876bb5a1bb3af89f2e33b/data/real/basic.lean#L12

Actually, it is a complex (no pun intended) definition that probably depends on dozens or hundreds of other definitions. Reducing all of these recursively will take a long time and create some huge and completely unhelpful output.

On the other hand, `nat` is a parameter-less inductive type. There is nothing to reduce there.